# p5.js: Random movement of drawing tool

Tags: p5.js

I coded this drawing tool:

```js
var a = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0, 0, 255);
}

function draw() {
  fill(0, 255, 255, random(255));
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);
  rotate(a);
  textSize(120);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text('*', 0, 0);
  rotate(a);
  a = a + 0.08;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Now I would like to have a movement, without doing it with the cursor. I have thought about something like this:

```js
var a;

function centerCanvas() {
  var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
  var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
  a.position(x, y);
}

function setup() {
  a = createCanvas(windowHeight, windowHeight);
  centerCanvas();
}

function draw() {
  fill(0, 255, 255, random(255));
  var x =
    windowHeight / 2 +
    sin(frameCount * 0.01) * cos(frameCount * 0.04) * windowHeight / 3;
  var y =
    windowHeight / 2 +
    cos(frameCount * 0.01) * sin(frameCount * 0.04) * windowHeight / 3;
  rotate(a);
  textSize(120);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text('*', 0, 0);
  rotate(a);
  a = a + 0.08;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It also would be cool if the movement would be random inside the canvas. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: `translate(Math.random(windowWidth), Math.random(windowHeight));`not yet what you want but a first step to randomness.

Comment: @Franck Instead of "translate(mouseX, mouseY);"? This doesn't work ...

Comment: @Anna_B Worked in a way for me. But the circle drawing remained in the corner.

Comment: Error from p5 seems pretty clear: `rotate(a);`... in your first script `a` is a number, as expected, but in the second script, `a` is the whole renderer (the return value of `createCanvas`). Why not go back to passing in a number as you did in the first script?

Comment: @Anna_B Please try `translate((++x + Math.random()*100) % windowWidth,(++y + Math.random()*100) % windowHeight);` You need `var x = 0;
var y = 0;` like for `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (almost) worked for me:

```js
let wander;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0, 0, 0);
  
  wander = new Vehicle(0, 0);
  
}

function draw() {
  
  wander.wander();
  wander.update();
  wander.edges();
  wander.show();
  
}


class Vehicle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = createVector(x, y);
    this.vel = createVector(1, 0);
    this.acc = createVector(0, 0);
    this.maxSpeed = 4;
    this.maxForce = 0.2;
    this.r = 16;

    this.wanderTheta = PI / 2;
    this.xoff = 0;
  }

  wander() {
    let angle = noise(this.xoff) * TWO_PI * 2;
    let steer = p5.Vector.fromAngle(angle);
    steer.setMag(this.maxForce);
    this.applyForce(steer);
    this.xoff += 0.01;
  }

  applyForce(force) {
    this.acc.add(force);
  }

  update() {
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.vel.limit(this.maxSpeed);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.set(0, 0);
  }

  show() {
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(255);
    push();
    translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    rotate(this.vel.heading());
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    textSize(120);
    fill(0, 255, 255, random(255));
    text("*", 0, 0);
    pop();
  }

  edges() {
    let hitEdge = false;
    if (this.pos.x > width + this.r) {
      this.pos.x = -this.r;
      hitEdge = true;
    } else if (this.pos.x < -this.r) {
      this.pos.x = width + this.r;
      hitEdge = true;
    }
    if (this.pos.y > height + this.r) {
      this.pos.y = -this.r;
      hitEdge = true;
    } else if (this.pos.y < -this.r) {
      this.pos.y = height + this.r;
      hitEdge = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Using P5.js's `noise` function is a really accurate way to represent wandering. With a little tinkering you can get the effect you want.

**EDIT**

This is your (debugged) code:

```js
let a;
let r;

function centerCanvas() {
  var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
  var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
  a.position(x, y);
}

function setup() {
  a = createCanvas(windowHeight, windowHeight);
  centerCanvas();
}

function draw() {
  fill(0, 255, 255, random(255));
  const x = windowHeight / 2 +
    sin(frameCount * 0.01) * cos(frameCount * 0.04) * windowHeight / 3;
  const y = windowHeight / 2 +
    cos(frameCount * 0.01) * sin(frameCount * 0.04) * windowHeight / 3;
  translate(x, y);
  rotate(a * 0.08);
  textSize(50);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text('*', 0, 0);
  a += 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, a lot of code! It stops sometimes. It would be cool to have it without these stops. I'll try to work with it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
var a = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var delta = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0, 0, 255);
}

function draw() {
  fill(0, 255, 255, random(255));
  x = x + 2 + Math.random();
  y = y + 0.5 + Math.random();
  x = x * delta;
  y = y * delta;
  if (x < 0) delta = -1;
  translate((x) % windowWidth,(y) % windowHeight);
  rotate(a);
  textSize(120);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text('*', 0, 0);
  rotate(a);
  a = a + 0.08;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's just a random placement. But it should look like it's drawing.

Comment: @Anna_B Sorry, no good solution found. For inspiration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktPnruyC6cc

Comment: Thank you! Now it looks better, but not really like a random drawing. I'll think about it.